# One of my lists shouldn't change, but it does

Tags: list, python-3.x

So I have a function:

```
def flip_stack(stack, nFlip):
    """flip_stack(list, num)
    Edits stack to flip the first nFlip elements in the stack."""
    newStack = stack[:nFlip]
    for element in newStack:
        stack.remove(element)
    newStack.reverse()
    stack = newStack + stack
    return(stack)
```

Given

```
stack = [2, 3, 1, 4, 0]
nFlip = 3
stack = [1, 3, 2, 4, 0]
```

This much of it works. It flips the stack at the correct place.

However, when I use that later:

```
difStack = stack
flip_pancakes(difStack, difStack.index(max(difStack)) + 1) # flip stack so largest number is at front
print(stack)
```

stack suddenly becomes [0]
Does anyone know why? The flip_pancakes() function in the second bit of code should have only changed difStack, right?

And I realize that that that particular bit is really messy; any way to improve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers have correctly identified the issue, that you're modifying the list that gets passed into the function. However, I think their suggested solution is not ideal.

Instead of copying part of the list, then looping to remove some of the values, just do a pair of slices and concatenate:

```
def flip_stack(stack, nFlip):
    return stack[nFlip-1::-1] + stack[nFlip:]
```

This does not modify `stack` at all. The first slice has a negative "step" term, so it reverses the order of the values.

If you did want the flipping to happen in place, rather than creating a new list for the new ordering, You could do a slice assignment, rather than forming a new list by concatenating two slices. Here's how I'd do that:

```
def flip_stack_inplace(stack, nFlip):
    stack[:nFlip] = stack[nFlip-1::-1]
```

This version doesn't explicitly return anything (which means it really returns `None`, since that's Python's default return value). All of the changes are done directly within the `stack` list.

Example usage:

```
>>> s = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> print(flip_stack(s, 3))
[3, 2, 1, 4, 5]
>>> print(s)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> flip_stack_inplace(s, 3)
>>> print(s)
[3, 2, 1, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Yeah, I actually did want stack to be changed directly, but I didn't know if that was possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The *difstack* list isn't a new list.

Change this:

```
difStack = stack
```

To this:

```
 difStack = stack[:]
```

Answer (score 0):

`difStack = stack` doesn't clone `stack`. Both of those variables still point to the same list object.

If you want to clone a list, slice it:

```
difStack = stack[:]
```

Or pass it into the `list()` builtin:

```
difStack = list(stack)
```

Comment: Okay, thanks, I get that, but why does stack change to 0? I didn't change difStack to 0... did I?

Comment: @user2540878: You call `stack.remove` in the function.